# cant load two combo boxes with different datasources using c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am loading two combo boxes with two different datasources from sql using a datatable and i'm loading it when the form loads but i dont know the reason only one combo box is filled (one at the top always fills the other one doesn't) and i have checked the datatables they are working fine

```
           private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.Text == "")
        {

            customer cc1 = new customer();
            comboBox2.DataSource = cc1.getplatenumber();
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "Platenumber";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Platenumber";
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Platenumber");
        }
        if (comboBox1.Text == "")
        {
            customer cc = new customer();
            DataTable dt = cc.getitems();
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Item_no";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Itemname";
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Itemname");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }


    }
```

any help ?

Comment: You mean the code inside the 2nd if block runs but nothing loads in combobox right?

Comment: Check if this condition meets `if (comboBox1.Text == "")`. try loading without the condition in place.

Comment: if you do get data in `dt` (the datatable) then make sure you bind the right column to the combobox. Check if the column name is spelled correctly.

Comment: everything is correct its just that when i put 2nd condition in place of 1st condition then combobox1 gets filled and combobox2 gets empty ......only one combobox is getting filled the other doesn't gets filled

Answer (score 0):

Step through the code

- Ensure that the code inside the 2nd if block runs, as Rohit suggests
- Verify that dt is filled as you expect
- Check the strings you're using to extract data - are "Item_no" and "Itemname" correct?

Comment: its running both statements when i am running them button click function but it isn't working on form load function any help?

Comment: Look at how your form is initialised. Try putting a message box or debug output in the code to see where it stops, or better, step through the code and see what it's doing.